# How to store users' modifications in specific directory in MySQL 

Tags: mysql, database, dataset

I would like all INSERTs and DELETEs of a specific user to be stored in a specific folder on the disc. Each user deals with different data set. So that there would be no possibility of conflicting.

Is this possible in mysql...?

Is there any way to configure mysql to do so...?

Regards,

UDAY

Comment: Your question is not clear, what you mean by "write activity" ? INSERT?

Comment: Write activity in a database mean inserts and updates...

Comment: So you want to export all SQLs by specified user if it is INSERT or UPDATE to separate folder?

Comment: I want this to happen at the data write time itself. suppose, if 1 users tried to insert some data, I want the first users data to be on "/home/mysql/data/user1/" folder and the other into  "/home/mysql/data/user2/" folder. I hope i got it now.

Comment: Still not understand, "users data" is data in tables? If so, then it is total anti-pattern.User is DB user or OS user?

Comment: users I mean mysql users who were given grants to access the database.

Comment: user data I mean whay they insert/update in database tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor/analyze mysql user activity with mysql-proxy:

http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy_Cookbook#Monitoring_and_logging_techniques

You can also dump queries, result data, etc...

Comment: Is proxy able to direct the specific user writes to a specific directory as i asked above....? this is what i need at the end.